# How to write SQL statement with joins, set subtraction, subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

We have an issue-tracking system for our software. Yesterday my boss gave me the task of finding all issues in the issue table submitted by this certain guy with an ID of 2992:

issue table:

```
issue_id (int)
submitter_id (int)
...other fields
```

Then for *each issue* in that result set I had to look at another table to find who was subscribed to it:

issue_subscribers table:

```
issue_id (int) [primary key to issue table]
subscriber_id (int)
...other fields
```

I had these ID numbers (3247, 4748, 7430, 8429) which represent other users, and if any of them were NOT subscribed, I had to add them as subscribers to the issue. This means simply adding a new row to issue_subscribers table.

This was way over my head. I ended up doing this with 3 different queries in a Java JDBC program instead of trying to figure it out with pure SQL. But now I'm curious how it could be done. Is this a simple procedure for professional SQL guys? Is it possible to write a single query to do this? How would it be done?

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: Do you have a table containing all the possible `subscribers`?

Comment: In `issue_subscribers` table, is it `primary key` or `foreign key`?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing:

- subscriber_id is a `foreign key` to some table that hold all possible `subscribers`.
- You only need to do this with issue 2992 and subscribers 3247, 4748, 7430 and 8429.

You could write following SQL query:

```
Insert Into issue_subscribers
(
  issue_id,
  subscriber_id
  -- and other fields if necessary
)
(
  Select 2992 issue_id,
         subscriber_id
         -- and other fields if necessary
    From subscribers subs -- table that holds all possible subscribers
   Where subscriber_id In (3247, 4748, 7430, 8429)
     And Not Exists (Select 1
                       From issue_subscribers iss
                      Where issue_id = 2992
                        And iss.subscriber_id = subs.subscriber_id)

);
```

In case you would need to use it for other issues and subscribers you would need to change the ids to parameters, and specify the `subscriber_ids` of the `in` condition some other way (perhaps a subselect of some kind).